# Count of number occurrences in a column

Tags: sql, group-by, count

I have the following table

```
actor_id    movie_id
---------------------
   1           20
   2           10
   3            8
   4            6
   1           21
```

I need the following output

```
actor_id    movie_count
-----------------------
   1           2
   2           1
   3           1
   4           1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "aggregate". To count how many movies there are for each actor you can do:

```
select
  actor_id,
  count(*) as movie_count
from t
group by actor_id
```

Now, if you need to count how many **different** movies are for each actor, you can do:

```
select
  actor_id,
  count(distinct movie_id) as movie_count
from t
group by actor_id
```

You should ask another question if you change the expected result. Anyway, here's the augmented query that adds the first name of the actor:

```
select
  c.*, 
  a.first_name, 
  a.id
from (
  select
    actor_id,
    count(*) as movie_count
  from t
  group by actor_id
) c
join actor a on a.actor_id = c.actor_id
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Now I would like to group the actor_id with their first_name and id which are in another table. For example, I want the output with these columns, actor_id, first_name, movie_count.

Comment: @ParthBute Added the first name of the actor.

Answer (score 1):

You need to count all the rows grouped by actor_id.
You can use below query

```
select actor_id,count(*) Movie_count from tableName
group by actor_id
order by actor_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` to aggregate

```
select actor_id,count(*) as movie_count
from table_name
group by actor_id
```

Comment: Now I would like to group the actor_id with their first_name which are in another table. For example, I want the output with these columns, actor_id, first_name, movie_count.

Comment: @ParthBute: you can use `select actor_id,first_name,count(*) as movie_count
from table_name
group by actor_id,first_name`

Comment: @ParthBute : Assuming you have   actor_id, first_name and movie_id in some table. if not please share the table details where first_name exists.

Comment: first_name and id are in the artist's table where id and actor_id are correlated from artists and movies_actors table respectively

Comment: Try this one: `select artist.id as actor_id, artist.first_name, count(*) as movie_count from artist left join movie_actors on artist.id=movie_actors.actor_id group by  artist.id, artist.first_name`